# JQUERY CSS - Scroll Bar setting to selected option visible

Tags: jquery, css

I have a side bar displaying menu items and it has vertical scrollbar . If I scroll down and click on one of the menu items the coming up page displays the clicked menu item as selected . But the problem is I have to scroll down to see the selected menu item .Is there any way I can scroll down automatically to that clicked ( Selected ) menu item ?

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/4XZMb/1944/

Here in this case I clicked on "Datalog" but it is down and I have scroll down to see that menu item

Thanks for your help.

```
<div id="sidemenu" style="height: 150px; width:200px; overflow-y: auto">
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li><a href="#">ActionScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CHILL</a></li>                         
    <li><a href="#">C++</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JAVA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pascal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cobol</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Datalog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SQL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PL/SQL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ELAN</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sidemenu').scrollTop($(".nav-list li.active").offset().top);
});
```

If you like to you can also do it with `.animate()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sidemenu').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".nav-list li.active").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/4XZMb/1948/)